# Чем можно заменить switch/case в данном коде?

Tags: c, массивы, switch, case

```
void generator(const int rows, const int columns, char field[rows][columns]){

    char c[] = {'@','#','$','%','^','&','*','+',' '};
    char l ;
    int c1 = rand() % columns;
    int c2 = rand() % columns;
    int count1=0,count2=0,count3=0,count4=0,count5=0,count6=0,count7=0,count8=0;
    while(c2 == c1){
        c2 = rand() % columns;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        if (i == c1 || i == c2)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                field[y][i] = ' ';
            }
            continue;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            l = c[rand()%(columns-2)];
            switch (l)
            {
            case '@':
                if (count1<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count1++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '#':
                if (count2<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count2++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '$':
                if (count3<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count3++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '%':
                if (count4<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count4++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '^':
                if (count5<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count5++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '&':
                if (count6<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count6++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                if (count7<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count7++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            case '+':
                if (count8<rows)
                {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    count8++;
                }else
                {
                    y--;
                }
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для чего вам чем-то заменять switch?

Comment: Условных операторов в C/C++ два - `switch()` и `if() else`. Т.е. вместо свитча можно написать многоэтажную конструкцию из ифов. Но вообще как раз `switch()` сделан чтобы заменить нечитаемые многоэтажные конструкции из  `if()`

Comment: @DmitryK, конкретно тут можно заменить на один `if` внутри `for`. Но придётся и ещё кое что изменить.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов я писал для общего случая. А так - да, согласен, конкретно в этом коде можно заменить на один `if()`

Comment: Кстати, у вас тут 2 возможных ошибки. 1 - при `columns==1`, будет вечный цикл `while(c2 == c1){ c2 = rand() % columns; }`  2 - `columns==2`, будет деление на ноль `l = c[rand()%(columns-2)];`

Comment: что этот код должен делать?

Answer (score 0):

Код внутри свитча отличается только счётчиками операций, связанных индивидуально с каждой. Можно создать структуру из имени операции и счётчика. Потом случайно выбираете *адрес* этой структуры и выполняете идентичные действия, не зависящие с именем операции.

*В вашем коде доступ к массиву `l = c[rand()%(columns-2)];` очень опасный. Вы уверены, что размер массива `c` больше или равен `columns-2` ?*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct s_char_int t_char_int ;
struct s_char_int {
    char c ;
    int  n ;
} ;
void generator(const int rows, const int columns, char field[rows][columns]){
    t_char_int cn[] = {{'@',0},{'#',0},{'$',0},
      {'%',0},{'^',0},{'&',0},{'*',0},{'+',0},
      {' ',0}};
    char l ;
    int c1 = rand() % columns;
    int c2 = rand() % columns;
    while(c2 == c1){
        c2 = rand() % columns;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        if (i == c1 || i == c2)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                field[y][i] = ' ';
            }
            continue;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            t_char_int * r = & cn[rand()%(columns-2)] ;
            l = r->c;
            if ( l != ' ' ) {
                if ( r->n < rows) {
                    field[y][i] = l;
                    r->n++;
                } else  {
                    y--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```